# NoReverseMatch at /

Tags: python, django

Estou fazendo umas aulas de Python com Django e está dando esse erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'courses'

urlpatterns = [
  path('', views.index, name='index'),
  path('<str:slug>/', views.details, name='details'),
  path('<str:slug>/anuncios/', views.announcements, name='announcements'),
  path('<str:slug>/anuncios/<pk>', views.show_announcement, name='show_announcement'),
  path('<str:slug>/inscricao/', views.enrollment, name='enrollment'),
  path('<str:slug>/cancelar-inscricao/', views.undo_enrollment, name='undo_enrollment'),
  path('<str:slug>/aulas/', views.lessons, name='lessons'),
  path('<str:slug>/aulas/<pk>/', views.lesson, name='lesson'),
  path('<str:slug>/materiais/<pk>/', views.material, name='material'),
```

]

views.py

```
@login_required
@enrollment_required
def announcements(request, slug):
     course = request.course
     template = 'courses/announcements.html'
     context = {
        'course': course,
        'announcements': course.announcements.all(),
     }
    return render(request, template, context, slug)

@login_required
@enrollment_required
def show_announcement(request, slug, pk):
   course = request.course
   announcement = get_object_or_404(course.announcement.all(), pk=pk)
   form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
   if form.is_valid():
      comment = form.save(commit=False)
      comment.user = request.user
      comment.announcement = announcement
      comment.save()
      form = CommentForm()
      messages.success(request, 'Seu comentário foi enviado com sucesso')
   template = 'courses/show_announcement.html'
   context = {
     'course': course,
     'announcement': announcement,
     'form': form,
  }
  return render(request, template, context, pk, slug)
```

show_annoucement.html

```
   {% extends "courses/course_dashboard.html" %}

   {% block dashboard_content %}
   {% for announcement in announcements %}
    <div class="well">
    <h2>
            <a href="{% url 'courses:show_announcement' Course.slug 
    announcement.pk %}">{{ announcement.title }}</a>
    </h2>
   {{ announcement.content|linebreaks }}
   <p>
           <a href="{% url 'courses:show_announcement' Course.slug 
    announcement.pk %}#comments">
             <i class="fa fa-comments-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
             {% with comments_count=announcement.comments.count %}
             {{ comments_count }}       Comentário{{ comments_count|pluralize 
             }}
             {% endwith %}
           </a>
    </p>
 </div>
 {% empty %}
 <div class="well">
    <h2>Nenhum anúncio criado</h2>
 </div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

course_dashboard.html

```
{% extends "accounts/dashboard.html" %}

{% block breadcrumb %}
{{ block.super }}
   <li>/</li>
   <li><a href="{% url 'courses:announcements' course.slug %}">{{ course }} 
   </a></li>
{% endblock %}

{% block menu_options %}
  <li class="pure-menu-heading">
  {{ course }}
  </li>
  <li>
     <a href="{% url 'courses:lessons' course.slug %}">
         <i class="fa fa-video-camera"></i>
            Aulas e Materiais
     </a>
  </li>
 <li>
    <a href="#">
       <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>
       Informações
   </a>
</li>
<li>
   <a href="{% url 'courses:announcements' course.slug %}">
       <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
      Anúncios
  </a>
```

Fórum de dúvidas

{{ block.super }}
   {% endblock %

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Edita a pergunta e adiciona a parte do template `base.html` que está a originar o erro.

Comment: @drec4s  ai está o base.html.

Comment: Esse parte do template não tem nenhum URL para a view 'show_annoucement'. Queria ver era a parte dentro do `block content` da view que origina o erro.

Comment: @drec4s  coloquei o show_annnoucemnt.html e course_dashboard.html. Espero que seja um desses, por que tem mitas heranças  nos templates.

Answer (score 0):

Penso que o problema está relacionado com os urls no `show_annoucement.html`. A variável `course` dentro do contexto course é com "c" minúsculo:

```
   {% extends "courses/course_dashboard.html" %}

   {% block dashboard_content %}
   {% for announcement in announcements %}
    <div class="well">
    <h2>
      <a href="{% url 'courses:show_announcement' slug=course.slug pk=announcement.pk %}">
        {{ announcement.title }}
      </a>
    </h2>
   {{ announcement.content|linebreaks }}
   <p>
     <a href="{% url 'courses:show_announcement' slug=course.slug pk=announcement.pk %}#comments">
             <i class="fa fa-comments-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
             {% with comments_count=announcement.comments.count %}
             {{ comments_count }}       Comentário{{ comments_count|pluralize 
             }}
             {% endwith %}
           </a>
    </p>
 </div>
 {% empty %}
 <div class="well">
    <h2>Nenhum anúncio criado</h2>
 </div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: consertei o C course e agora  aparece o código todo na tela

Comment: O que queres dizer com código todo?

Comment: não aparece a pagina e sim o código dela no localhost

Comment: coloquei um print de tela ai  na postagem

Comment: Isso é porque estás a passar parametros a mais dentro da função [render](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#render). Apenas deves passar `return render(request, template, context)`. (as variáveis slug e pk não devem ser incluidas no render)